# Adding three20 libraries to an iPhone project

Tags: iphone, three20

I'm adding Three20 to my project but I seem to be missing

```
libThree20-Xcode3.2.2.a
libThree20-Xcode3.2.5.a
libThree20.a
Three20UnitTests-Xcode3.2.2.octest
Three20UnitTests-Xcode3.2.5.octest
Three20UnitTests.octest
```

in the `Three20.xcodeproj` project. I haven't been able to find these, eg. by using Spotlight. For reference I'm following the instructions given [here](https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/Articles/AboutModules.mdown) under "Migrating to the New Three20".

What am I not doing?

Comment: You should follow the steps explained here : https://github.com/facebook/three20

Comment: That was my first port of call. Did that. Then tried the link I gave (which is very similar). Then tried http://three20.info/ and the python terminal script. The frameworks all appear in my project but the libraries are all in red. Maybe it won't turn out to be a problem.... Hey-ho.

Comment: it's not necessarily a problem that they are in red. What's the output of compilation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to link all of those libraries with your application. The instructions you are following aren't very clear about that. The unit tests for example, are simply for testing the three20 project itself and you won't want them included in your final application. The 3 different lib targets for each project, as far as I can tell, simply have a different target SDK setting for each. You only need to check and include 1 in your project. I just check the main one from each project, without the XCode version suffix.

So first, be sure to follow the "Migrating to three20" step 3 very closely. The projects below the main three20 project ALSO need to be dragged into your project to be built. Being listed under the main three20 project's dependencies, at first seems as if they'll be included, but they must also be dragged into your project.

Second, step 5 should read "Ensure that the checkbox beside ONE lib file is checked in EACH three20 project. Do not check any octest."

Hope that works for you.